# Is it legal to initialize multiple overlapping fields in a union's member initializer list?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have this union:

```
union Foo
{
    uint32_t u32;
    struct
    {
        uint32_t a : 10;
        uint32_t b : 10;
        uint32_t c : 10;
        uint32_t d : 2;
    };

    Foo() : a(0), b(1), c(2), d(3)
    {
    }
};
```

We have a tool that analyzes C++ code for potential bugs, and it has a false positive where it thinks that `u32` hasn't been initialized when I write this.

I found that VC++ will let me write this member initializer list:

```
Foo() : u32(0), a(0), b(1), c(2), d(3)
```

It does shut up the tool, but it looks... mightily dubious. (Edit based on the comments: GCC and Clang won't accept it, so mightily dubious seems justified.)

For structures, member initializers are executed in their order of definition in the structure. Is there something similar for unions that ensures that this doesn't end up zeroed because of `u32(0)`?

We don't have great pretenses of portability. Right now, this project targets Windows, but it might target iOS and Android in the future. I can pretty much guarantee that it won't show up on strange and exotic platforms though.

Of course, I can just set `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in the constructor's body, which sidesteps the whole issue (or I can disable the warning), but it got me curious.

Comment: Not an answer per se but, is there no directive (pragma or something) to let that tool know it's OK in this specific case?

Comment: [gcc-5.1 rejects it](http://ideone.com/15OaqR)

Comment: @Amit, I'm not running out of workarounds for this specific issue. :) There is one, yes.

Comment: @PcAF, [Clang-3.8 accepts it](https://godbolt.org/g/G9X2Dm).

Comment: So I'd use that before I'd go into the "overlapping initializers" for the sake of readability and safety.

Comment: Well, yes, of course, that won't make it much further than my local Git repository. But I thought that was fun enough to ask.

Comment: Anonymous struct is not standard C++.  So the language lawyer answer is "this is ill-formed and the compiler can do whatever it wants after it issues a diagnostic".

Comment: @T.C., you can trivially replace the anonymous structure with any type that you prefer and the question will stand.

Comment: @zneak Your "clang accepts" example doesn't actually have `u32(0)` in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4594

12.6.2/§? (Under §9):

> [ Note: [...] —end note ] **An attempt to
>   initialize more than one non-static data member of a union renders the program ill-formed.** [ Note: [...] —end note ]